# How to load the directive controller defined in a closure into the test spec

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have chosen to create a solution based upon option 2 in the accepted answer to this question:
[Unit-testing directive controllers in Angular without making controller global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314293/unit-testing-directive-controllers-in-angular-without-making-controller-globally).

My code looks something like this:

```
(function () {

    function myCtrl($scope) {
        //All my controller code.
    };

    myAppModule.directive('myDirective', function($compile, $timeout) {

        return {

            restrict: 'E',

            replace: true,

            controller: myCtrl,

            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {

                return {
                post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    //more code and stuff.
                }
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

My simple question is; because the controller is not defined in the scope of the module, how do I load it in my test file?

Answer (score 0):

As the answer explains, you must split the code above in three files:

- Prefix with all code upto `function myCtrl($scope) {`
- Controller code
- Postfix

While building your application, you concatenate these three files into one and use the result for the productive code.

For tests, you simply include the middle file. This does create your controller in the global namespace of the test. In the productive code, the closure avoids this pollution.

Comment: Right, so my solution as it stands cannot be loaded into the test suite because it is already wrapped in a closure and therefore invisible even when loaded? In which case I'll choose option 1.

Comment: Exactly. In my own code, I often pollute the global namespace with just a single symbol and put everything into that one - which is just a variant of using the angularjs module system.