# How to add bindings to a controller in a directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive like this with the myGoal property passed in as a binding

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirective', {
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'goalController',
        controller: function() {
            if (this.myGoal === 'Be awesome') {
               //do stuff
            }
        }
    });
```

In a unit test I need to pass bindings to my controller when compiling the directive.

I can test the controller independently by doing this:

```
var ctrl = $controller('goalController', {}, { myGoal: 'Be awesome' });
expect(ctrl.myGoal).toEqual('Be awesome');
```

but I need to test the controller and directive as one

```
$compile('<my-directive></my-directive')(scope);
```

and have the bindings passed to the controller.

How do I add bindings when compiling the directive?

Comment: Where is the code that is registering your controller to angular?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314293/unit-testing-directive-controllers-in-angular-without-making-controller-global

Comment: It's a third party library directive doing the registering which is why I dont know how to do this but I need to test my directive and controller that the library is registering. In order to test properly I need to pass in bindings like the library does.